# Не подключаются свойства плагина "mmenu" extensions: [ 'widescreen', 'theme-black' ]

Tags: javascript

Проблема в чём, не применяются свойства плагина mmenu. Вроде бы подписал всё правильно, и в index.html вроде бы всё подключил привильно. Но почему-то свойствва не подключаются.

```
$(function () {

    $('#my-menu').mmenu({
        extensions: [ 'widescreen', 'theme-black', 'effect-menu-slide', 'pagedim-black' ]
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>S&Mitler</title>
<meta name="description" content="">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<meta property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mmenu/source/jquery.mmenu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mmenu/source/extensions/jquery.mmenu.themes.css">

<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#1a1a1a">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#1a1a1a">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#1a1a1a">

<style>body { opacity: 0; overflow-x: hidden; } html { background-color: #1a1a1a; }</style>
```

```
    <div id="my-header">

        <header class="site-header" style="background-image: url(img/top-bg.jpg)">
           <div class="top-line">
                <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="img/logo-2.svg" alt="Салон красоыт Смитлер"></a>
                <div class="phone hidden-xs"><i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> +7 (900) 922-99-30</div>
                <a href="#my-menu" class="hamburger hamburger--emphatic">
                <span class="hamburger-box">
                    <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                </span>
                </a>

            <nav id="my-menu">
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Парикмахерский сервис</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Косметологический сервис</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Маникюрный сервис</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Массаж и SPA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Солярий</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Наши специалисты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ноовости</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Прайс-лист</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Наши сертификаты</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">О салоне</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


           </div> 

        </header>

    </div>


  <div id="my-content">
```

```
  <div id="my-footer">


  </div>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">
<script src="js/scripts.min.js"></script>
<script src="libs/mmenu/source/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
```

Comment: А саму библиотеку jQuery Вы подключили?

Comment: @humster_spb Если вы имеете ввиду через <script src="libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> в index.html то да но даже так не работает. Проблема в том что само выпадающее меню работает а свойства нет.

Comment: А что в консоли? Ошибки есть какие-то?

Comment: Вот что пишет в консоли браузера.    Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:3000/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
:3000/#my-menu:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:3000/fonts/FiraSansRegular/FiraSansRegular.woff
:3000/#my-menu:1 Slow network is detected. Fallback font will be used while loading: http://localhost:3000/fonts/RalewayRegular/RalewayRegular.woff

Comment: может быть, не хватает стилевых файлов? в документации http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/  указано, что надо подключать jquery.mmenu.css и jquery.mmenu.themes.css

Comment: @humster_spb Попробовал <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mmenu/source/jquery.mmenu.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/mmenu/source/extensions/jquery.mmenu.themes.css"> Подключил, без результатно.

Comment: судя по тому, что у Вас localhost, браузер мог закешировать прежнее состояние страницы и ничего не изменить - почистите кеш, обновите и посмотрите ещё раз

Comment: ну и приведите в вопросе полный код страницы, чтобы было видно, где, что и в какой последовательности Вы подключаете, где и как вызываете и т.д.

Comment: @humster_spb Я вставил полный код в вопрос. Кеш только что почистил но вреравно не помогло(

Comment: не вижу у Вас в коде подключения библиотеки jquery, также непонятно, где именно Вы вызываете $('#my-menu').mmenu({

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71034/discussion-between-brafik-and-humster-spb).